# Oracle Identify not unique values in a clob column of a table

Tags: oracle, compare, clob

I want to identify all rows whose content in a clob column is not unique.

The query I use is:

```
select
  id,
  clobtext
from
  table t
where 
    (select count(*) from table innerT where dbms_lob.compare(innerT.clobtext, t.clobtext) = 0)>1
```

However this query is very slow. Any suggestions to speed it up? I already tried to use the dbms_lob.getlength function to eliminate more elements in the subquery but I didn't really improve the performance (feels the same).

To make it more clear an example:

table

ID | clobtext

1  | a

2  | b

3  | c

4  | d

5  | a

6  | d

After running the query. I'd like to get (order doesn't matter):

1  | a

4  | d

5  | a

6  | d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've generated checksums (in my C# code) for each clob.

Whilst this will inccur a one off increase in io (to generate the checksum)
subsequent scans will be quicker, and you can index the value too

TK has a good PL\SQL example here:
[Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1493406836464)